# How to generate entity framework model from client side?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity

Can I generate entity framework model by clicking button in browser in client-side and save it back to web server PC?

Comment: I tried with edmgen.exe, but haven't got any results yet

Comment: Do you mean to create  an object and save it in a database on button click?
My other guess is do you mean to generate class in run-time and save it in an assembly on the server?

Comment: I am about process after creating object and saving it in a database. i want to generate EF model from browser by chosing db that located on sql server. after clicking on button, i want that, EF model generated fully and saved on web server.is it possible? Some idea please.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by generating entity framework model? Do you mean creating edmx? Or do you mean creating a regular object from data, and saving it in database? Could you perhaps elaborate on what specifically you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EdmGen is the way to go if you're sure this is the best solution to your problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896270.aspx

If you're having problems with it could you please post the command line arguments you're using to call it?

You'll have to create a process in your web app (System.Diagnostics.Process) in order to kick off the executable from the browser side.

Answer (score 1):

As David Neale says EmdGen is an option, if that is really what you want.

There is also [EmdGen2](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EdmGen2), which has the advantage that it is able to work directly with the Edmx file:

> EdmGen2 is a command-line tool for the
>   Microsoft ADO.NET Entity Framework.
>   The tool can be used as a replacement
>   for the EdmGen.exe tool that ships
>   with the .Net framework 3.5 SP1.
>   EdmGen.exe can only read and write the
>   CSDL, SSDL & MSL file formats.
>   However, EdmGen2.exe can read and
>   write the EDMX file format used by the
>   Visual Studio design tools.
>   Additionally, EdmGen2.exe can
>   translate between EDMX and CSDL, SSDL
>   & MSL formats, and the source code can
>   act as examples on using the tooling
>   APIs defined in the
>   System.Data.Entity.Design assembly.
>
> Additionaly, EdmGen2.exe contains some
>   experimental functionality not found
>   in EdmGen.exe. Ankit Malpani, an
>   intern with Microsoft Research in
>   summer of 2008, and James Terwilliger,
>   a Post Doc researcher with MSR,
>   updated EdmGen2.exe with the ability
>   to identify inheritance
>   relatationships in relational database
>   schema. You can access this
>   functionality by using the
>   "RetrofitModel" option. The
>   RetrofitModel option connects to a
>   database instance and constructs an
>   EDM model (csdl, msl, ssdl, and edmx
>   files) that includes inheritance. The
>   tool uses data mining techniques to
>   identify TPT and TPH patterns in the
>   database instance, as well as vertical
>   partitioning, and constructs a
>   suitable model and mapping. To use the
>   tool, launch EdmGen2 with the
>   following arguments: